# How to search for multiple strings using .find

Tags: excel, vba

```
Column A has values in the below rows 
A1="This is a test string"
A2="Hello how are you"
A3="Today is a good day"
A4="This is a test match"
A5="What is the time now"
A6="Test cell"
A7="This is true"
```

I would like to find rows which have both "This" and "test". So the result should be "This is a test string" and "This is a test match"
Using excel-vba how can this be done?
Do we need to use a nested .find?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something along the lines of

```
for i = 1 to 7
    if instr(1, Cells(i, 1), "This", vbtextcompare) > 0 and instr(1, Cells(i, 1), "test", vbtextcompare) Then
        Msgbox Cells(i,1).Value
    end if
next i
```

You will need to mod this for your specific needs but this will look for both "This" and "test" in a cell and create a message box with the cells contents when found.